# Bgvideo won't play in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, background

I have tried to put a background video in the first page of the site.
With Safari, IE and Mozilla, the video expands to full screen mode, but not in Chrome. Any advice?  Here is the site for reference: http://www.camarche.es

```
video#bgvid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried in Windows and it doesn't. Do you know a way to fix it! @clearlight thank you a lot!

Comment: Works for me too in Chrome 56 (Win PC). Background is fully taken by video. Maybe try clearing your cache in Chrome (incase it's showing you an older version of page)? Or even rename to `test2.html` then it'll be classed as a new URL when testing. Seems broken for you only.